# python script runs fine and gives desired o/p in file but while converting to .exe using py2exe gives runtime error:maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, recursion, tkinter, runtime-error, py2exe

I am getting the following error (can't add all the lines of error due to space constraints here)

I am not able to understand where the recursion is going wrong, I don't think I have used any while or if loop either, it's mostly for loops then where its going wrong?

Error:

```
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\py2exe\hooks.py", line 291, in __getattr__
    self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

setup.py:

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['pcomparator.py'])
```

Python script:

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import fileinput


import tkinter


class Values(tkinter.Tk):
    """docstring for Values"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        stepOne = tkinter.LabelFrame(self, text=" 1. Enter Values ")
        stepOne.grid(row=0, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        self.Val1Lbl = tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Value 1")
        self.Val1Lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)
        self.Val1Txt = tkinter.Entry(stepOne)
        self.Val1Txt.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=2, sticky='WE')
        self.Val2Lbl = tkinter.Label(stepOne,text="Value 2")
        self.Val2Lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='E', padx=5, pady=2)
        self.Val2Txt = tkinter.Entry(stepOne)
        self.Val2Txt.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=2, sticky='WE')

        self.val1 = None
        self.val2 = None

        SubmitBtn = tkinter.Button(stepOne, text="Submit",command=self.submit)
        SubmitBtn.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='W', padx=5, pady=2)

    def submit(self):
        self.val1=self.Val1Txt.get()
        if self.val1=="":
            Win2=tkinter.Tk()
            Win2.withdraw()

        self.val2=self.Val2Txt.get()
        if self.val2=="":
            Win2=tkinter.Tk()
            Win2.withdraw()

        self.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Values(None)
    app.title('Values')
    app.mainloop() #this will run until it closes
    #Print the stuff you want.
    print(app.val1,app.val2)
    q = app.val1+'%20'+app.val2
    url="https://www.google.com/search?q=%s&source=lnms&tbm=shop&sa" % q
    print(url)
    f = open('output5.txt','w+')
    headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

    req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers = headers)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(respData,"html5lib")

    price = soup.find_all("span", text = re.compile('^\$'))

    for span in price:
        seller=span.parent.contents[1]
        desc=span.get_text()
        f.write(str(desc) + "\n") 
        f.write(str(seller) + "\n")  

    f.close()
    for line in fileinput.FileInput("output5.txt",inplace=1):
        if line.rstrip():
            print(line)
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what is on line 291 in your `hook.py` file?

Comment: Unable to decode this hook file                                                    
class SixImporter(type(module)):
      def __getattr__(self, name):
            if name in self.__moved_modules:
                renamed = self.__moved_modules[name]
                self.__finder.safe_import_hook(renamed, caller=self)
                mod = self.__finder.modules[renamed]
                # add the module again with the renamed name:
                self.__finder._add_module("six.moves." + name, mod)
                return mod
            else:
                raise AttributeError(name)

Comment: What space constraints are you talking about? You can have up to 65k characters in a question.

Comment: There does seam to be several issues documented about py2exe with a max recursion depth exceeded.

Comment: no it was giving me error that i can have only n only 30000 characters in the body of the question ....

Comment: Odd. Maybe answers can be longer. I know I have seen the 65k limiter somewhere.

Comment: but it was working fine for me till yesterday, I had tried py2exe to convert my script before then it created an exe file successfully it was working on my machine but it was not working for old windows version machines so I thought of trying with cx_Freeze as its cross platform having more options for customization and I downloaded some file which are required with it but the exe it created was not proper, the tkinter window closed very soon without asking for input.so again I switched back to py2exe ,but now this is also throwing errors.Although all my code is working fine as python scripts.

Comment: I have not spent a lot of time using py2exe so it will be hard for me to troubleshoot. Maybe someone else with more experience with that tool will help.

Comment: thats absolutely fine, thanks anyways :)